# iPhone Xs - Why is there a huge padding between the top border of my UIView and the top border of the safe area when using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am developing a custom camera on the iphone Xs Max.  My layout is below.  The only UIView's top, left, right, and bottom borders are anchored to the safe area.  Yet, what I am seeing is a huge black space between the top border of my video capture output and the top border of the safe view.  What is this black space and how do i calculate its height?

[image]

Layout:

[image]

[image]

UIView constraints:
[image]

code:

```
class NewCapturViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate  {

   var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init()
   var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!


   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       startAVCaptureSession()
   }


func startAVCaptureSession() {
    print("START CAPTURE SESSION!!")

    // Setting Up a Capture Session
    self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()

    // Configure input
    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)

    guard
        let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: videoDevice!) as AVCaptureInput,
        self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)else {return}

    self.captureSession.addInput(videoDeviceInput)

    // Capture video output
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.init()
    guard self.captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else {return}
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.init(label: "videoQueue"))
    self.captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)


    // start
    self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    self.captureSession.startRunning()


    // Display camera preview
    self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init(session: self.captureSession)

    // Use 'insertSublayer' to enable button to be viewable
    self.camViewOutlet.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer, at: 0)
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.camViewOutlet.frame
    self.previewFrame = previewLayer.frame


    print("previewLayer.frame: \(previewLayer.frame)")

}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have set the `Align Top` to the `Safe Area`. Just remember that this phone has a notch - so the safe area will be lower.

If you change the phone in your `Storyboard` to the `iPhone Xs` (as mentioned in the question), you will see that you have this gap. All you need to do is set the top constraint to the `Superview` rather than the `Safe Area`.

Comment: Please could you elaborate on 'Align Top to the Safe Area' - is this down programatically?.

Comment: @dean In one of the images, you show the constraints you made in the storyboard. Just click on the top constraint, and change the alignment to `Superview` rather than `Safe Area`.

Comment: I did what you suggested but I am still getting that black padding

Comment: @dean I assumed that should have worked. Since it doesn't, I'm not too sure of the issue. If this is important or you want more help, you can always upload the project to **GitHub** and link it in your question. Update me if you upload the project, and I will try and sort it out.

Comment: Thanks Geroge.  I appreciate that.

Comment: I have elaborated on the same question in the link below - there is also a project link at the bottom of the question as well.  Appreciate your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569868/iphone-xs-max-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-when-added-to-sublayer-of-view-occupie

Answer (score 1):

You should set layer frames in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, not in `viewDidLoad`. Note that sizes of views *change* but layers added by you remain static because they are not updated automatically with their container views:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

   self.previewLayer.frame = self.camViewOutlet.bounds
   self.previewFrame = previewLayer.frame
}
```

Also note the difference between `frame` and `bounds`. `camViewOutlet.frame` is relative to its superview (`self.view`) but `previewLayer` is put inside `camViewOutlet`, therefore you have to use `camViewOutlet.bounds`. Basically, because `camViewOutlet` is put X points below the top of the screen (the height of the safe area), `previewLayer` is also put X points below the top of `camViewOutlet`.

There are other small issues in your code.

Note that `viewWillAppear` *must* call `super.viewWillAppear` and it can be called multiple times, therefore you should never add views and layers inside it.

You should probably also not start capturing before `viewDidAppear` has been called.

Comment: Please could you elaborate with some code based on what I have above with respect to the viewDidLayoutSubviews? I'm not quite clear on your answer.  Great last two points you made.

Comment: @dean Updated with an example.

Comment: Also, noticed another issue with `bounds` vs `frame`.

Comment: would you know how to access the safe layout margins (top and borrom for portrait orientation)?  Because although the black padding has substantially been reduced, there appears to be a margin in place - thinner black space still.  i'm nearly there ...

Comment: @dean There must be some other problem I am missing. Anyway, the top safe area height should be equal to `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height`, also possible to get using `UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaInsets`.

Comment: @Sutlthan - i have implemented your suggestions above.  I have an update version of this question in the link below.  There is also a project folder link in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569868/iphone-xs-max-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-when-added-to-sublayer-of-view-occupie