# iPhone Xs Max: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer when added to sublayer of View occupies less than the safe area of the iphone x - why?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, iphone-x

I am trying to build a custom camera using a single view application with the new iPhone Xs Max.  With reference to the screenshot below, it can be seen that the video output displayed in AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer occupies less than the safe area of the screen on the iPhone x.  How do I calculate the space that has not been occupied?

How do I know that the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer occupies less than the safe area? Well, the top border of the top 'Button' is anchored to the top border of the safe area.  The bottom button is similarly anchored to the bottom of the bottom safe area.  Yet there is huge overlap!

Problem:

[image]

The layout of single view application: Button top constraint

[image]

Bottom white button bottom constraint:
[image]

All other layout constraints:

[image]

SWIFT:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate  {

var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init()
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
var previewFrame = CGRect.init()
var safeAreaFrame: CGRect = CGRect.init()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
      // This is (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 896.0)

      startAVCaptureSession()

}



override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print("viewDidLayoutSubviews ...")

    let sAreaFrame = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
    self.safeAreaFrame = sAreaFrame

    // self.safeAreaFrame - This is (0.0, 44.0, 414.0, 818.0)


    self.previewLayer.frame = view.bounds // // I have tried  self.previewLayer.frame = self.safeAreaFrame 
    self.previewFrame = previewLayer.frame
}




func startAVCaptureSession() {
    print("START CAPTURE SESSION!!")

    // Setting Up a Capture Session
    self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()

    // Configure input
    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)

    guard
        let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: videoDevice!) as AVCaptureInput,
        self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)else {return}

    self.captureSession.addInput(videoDeviceInput)

    // Capture video output
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.init()
    guard self.captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else {return}
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.init(label: "videoQueue"))
    self.captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)


    // start
    self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    self.captureSession.startRunning()


    // Display camera preview
    self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init(session: self.captureSession)

    // Use 'insertSublayer' to enable button to be viewable
    view.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer, at: 0)



}





}
```

PROJCT LINK:
https://github.com/babylon123/RectangleCapture

Comment: So is the problems the buttons, or just the camera preview part?

Comment: the camera preview does not occupy the full safearea.  i would like to know the dimension of  space occupied by the output preview (in the safe area) or determine the space that is not occupied by the preview in the safe area.

Comment: So you only want to know the space from the preview, or do you just want to resize the preview to what you want as well?

Comment: where does the preview sit relative to the safe area or superview. Either. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I downloaded your code. Unfortunately, I don't have a real device with a notch. I tried to run the code in the simulator and got a crash, which I assume is because there is no camera.

Comment: that is a problem. because the code works fine in all device except one with a notch.  that is the preview occupies the entire window.  but for the iphone x, this is not the case. thanls for trying though

Comment: I won't be able to further help (as I can't test), but, try uncommenting the code on line 89 and removing line 90. That's all I can think of at a glance. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think that the problem now is not the UI code but the resolution of the video. Note that the camera captures video in some resolution and the width/height ratio (aspect) of that resolution is different from the aspect of the screen. Look at [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlayer/1388915-videogravity).

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the aspect ratio. If you add this line it should work:

self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

Comment: correct it'll make the video full screen but it looks like after applying this the video looks a bit zoomed in. If you may check the snapchat app it is not zoomed in.
Could you please suggest any other options?
Thanks